# Getting element ID placed in multiple DIVs

Tags: jquery, html

I have a problem with getting an ID of the lowest element (image) placed in multiple DIVs after hover top DIV. Here is my structure:

```
<div id="dig-xx">
<div>
    <div>Content</div>
    <div><img src="some_picture.jpg" id="aig-xx" alt="" /></div>
</div>
```

How to get <img> ID after hover whole DIV with id="dig-xx"?
Thank You for Your response.

Comment: An `Id` must be unique, use `class` instead.

Comment: Thanks. How to get it if I have many DIVs with different -xx numbers? For example 100 DIVs: id="dig-1" ... id="dig-100"? Should I use class then? I need exact image ID after hover exact DIV.

Comment: I tried to use "$(this).children('img').attr('id');" but it gets ID when image is placed directly in the first DIV. $(this) makes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#dig-xx').on('hover', function(){

    var imgId = $(this).find('img').attr('id');
});
```

---

If you have Multiple instances then use `Attribute Starts with Selector`

```
$('[id^="dig"]').on('hover', function(){

    var imgId = $(this).find('img').attr('id');
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/deCum/)**